# What does CastStatusCode 2004 (APPLICATION_NOT_FOUND) mean?

Tags: google-play-services, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I encountered [this error code](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-application_not_found) in my application and was wondering why this might occur (when casting via Chromecast from an app). The definition doesn't help explain much. What would be a use case where this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Status code indicating that a requested application could not be found. Please read this release notes from April 20, 2021 for more information on status codes https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes?hl=en#april-20,-2021